# A Faulty Number Trick

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

This trick just isn't adding up for me:

> Take any whole number,
> Subtract a shorter whole number from it,
> Reverse what's left, then add 10 to it.
> You will find, for any number you've picked, your answer will match it!

How can that be possible?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I'm not sure this is a regular answer but ... Take any whole number

> integer - this is a whole number

Subtract a shorter whole number from it

> int - this is a shorter word for a whole number, and subtracting leaves eger

Reverse what's left, then add 10 to it

> rege + x (ten in Roman numerals)

You will find, for any number you've picked, your answer will match it!

> **regex** - this can match it!

Comment: Yes, this is exactly right!